# Compare two files in perl / python and print matching entries

Tags: python, perl

I have two files

File1.txt

```
123 abc
254 ded
256 ddw
```

File2.txt

```
123
256
```

output ( only matching entries in file1.txt)

```
123  abc
256  ddw
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python solution.

```
import sys

with open('file1.txt') as f:
    d = {line.split()[0]: line for line in f if line.strip()}

with open('file2.txt') as f:
    sys.stdout.writelines(d.get(line.strip(), '') for line in f)
```

Comment: Oops, there was python tag. ;)

Comment: Giving error
line 4, in <module>

    d = {line.split()[0]: line for line in f}

  File "sort.py", line 4, in <dictcomp>

    d = {line.split()[0]: line for line in f}

IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: @bio-code's, I updated the code to skip blank lines. Try again.

Answer (score 0):

Perl solution.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use autodie;

my %d;
{
    open my $fh, "File2.txt";
    while(<$fh>) {
        chomp;
        $d{$_} = 1;
    }
}

{
    open my $fh, "File1.txt";
    while(<$fh>) {
        my($f1) = split /\s+/, $_; # or alternatively match with a regexp
        print $_ if $d{$f1};
    }
}

__END__
```

Answer (score 0):

my Perl Solution

```
#! /usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;


open FILE1, "File1.txt" || die "Cannot find File1.txt";
open FILE2, "File2.txt" || die "Cannot find File2.txt";

my %hash;

while (<FILE1>) {
    chomp;
    my ($key, $value) = split;

    $hash{$key} = $value;
}

while (<FILE2>) {
    chomp;
    my $key = $_;
    print "$key $hash{$key}\n";
}
```